Can't access package server during docker-compose build (ERROR: network bridge not found)
Building and starting of my docker-compose project fails with the error:
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: network bridge not found

my docker-compose.yml file only contains:
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data:/app/data
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

for security reason the /etc/docker/daemon.json doesn't enable a network bridge by default:
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "iptables": true,
  "bridge": "none",
  "bip": "",
  "default-address-pools": [
    ...
  ],
  ...

Adding the following line to the docker-compose.yml doesn't solve the issue:
    network_mode: host

What is the right way to do?

I think the "bridge": "none" option disables the standard Docker NAT setup (and so, as much as you're running into this in the context of an image build, this is a generic Docker issue and not something programming-specfic).  Does anything else Docker-related actually work with this setup?

@DavidMaze Thanks for your comment, I managed to solve the issue, see the answer below. The application within the container is running well if it does not require to actively communicate with the outside, but building fails, because docker can't access the npm package server. But what I did not consider, was that enabling the network mode host, has to be done in build and running context separately.

In order to have the network bridge enabled during the build process, you have to use network: host within the build section of the docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      network: host
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data:/app/data
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

To also have the bridge available during container execution you would use network_mode: host in the myapp section. Like this:
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      network: host
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data:/app/data
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    network_mode: host

Further reference can be found in the Compose Build Specification and the Services top-level elements documentation.
